# How to handle Windows upload/download Dialog with Ruby-Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have to upload a file using windows upload dialog. How can i achieve it using ruby-rspec. Shall i use 3rd party tool as AutoIT or does Ruby provide any way of handling Window's based dialogs.

I have used this:

```
Class Upload
def upload_File() 
      filename= 'NewFile.xlsx'
      file = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename)
  @driver.find_element(:xpath,Upload::LINK_UPLOAD_FILE_XPATH).send_keys(file)
end
```

But it doesn't work directly on dialogs. It works if there is a field where i can provide the location of file directly on the webpage itself but not on windows dialog for file selection.

Comment: Ruby doesn't. AutoIT is probably the most stable way to handle file upload pop-up, so no reason to not use it.

Comment: Yes, but how to call AutoIt script from ruby script.                                  
def upload_File_To_Pulse        
      find(:css, ClassName::LINK_UPLOAD_FILE_CSS).click
      sleep 5
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:/AutoIt Scripts/FileUpload.exe")      
      sleep 5
      find(:xpath, ClassName::BTN_PULSE_POST_XPATH).click
     }
  end                                                                                                       This is what i have used. but i get error like " NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Runtime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I have used it years ago with this gem providing AutoIT bindings:  https://rubygems.org/gems/au3. See if that simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. IO is a class that handles input/output file operations. Added this piece of code in my Ruby-Rspec script and it worked.

```
f = IO.popen("D:/AutoIt_Scripts/FileUpload.exe")
      puts f.readlines
```

In AutoIT file i had written

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","D:\Upl\DemoUpload.xlsx")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

and saved it with .au3 extension.